# Excel 2010 Macro has run-time error -2147467259 (80004005): Invalid parameter

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, vba

I'm getting a run-time error `-2147467259 (80004005): Invalid parameter` when running a vba macro I created in Excel 2010. The error occurs when I try to set .majorUnitScale = xlMonths after setting .CategoryType = xlTimeScale. Trying to create a chart with .chartType = xlLineMarkers

The strange thing is that when I run this code in Excel 2007, it works flawlessly and produces a line chart as needed.

Here's part of the code:

```
dim myChtObj as ChartObject

Set myChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=202, Width:=340, Top:=28,Height:=182)

With myChtObj.Chart
    ' remove extra series
    Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
        .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop

    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers

    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Performance Trends"
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 12
    .ChartTitle.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .ChartTitle.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"

    With .Axes(xlCategory)
        .CategoryType = xlTimeScale
        .BaseUnit = xlMonths
        .MajorUnit = 2
        .MajorUnitScale = xlMonths   ' run-time error occurs here
        .MinorUnit = 1
        .MinorUnitScale = xlMonths

        .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mmm yy"
        .TickLabels.Orientation = 45
    End With
    .....
End with
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've had a similar phantom error when trying to set the `plotarea` dimensions. It may not be desirable/optimal, but check to see if the error persists if you `select` the axis in code and then do `selection.majorunitscale = xlMonths`

Comment: @DavidZemens - i tried your suggestion by selecting the category axis and then use `selection.majorunitscale = xlMonths` but still get the same run-time error.

Comment: bizarre. I get the same error even when trying to run the sample code provided from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208719(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: If you comment out the offending line, does the `MinorUnitScale` throw the same error? My guess is "Yes" but never hurts to ask.

Comment: @DavidZemens - thanks for researching this further. Yes, setting `minorunitscale` generates the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ash -

In your code, try adding series data and category labels prior to assigning the axis scales.

I can successfully run this code on a chart so long as there is at least 1 series, and the category axis labels are in date format.

I have uploaded a workbook to Google Docs which has the chart already created. Delete the chart, but leave the series data in columns B&C, then run the macro `AshOriginalWithAddSeries`.  All I have done really is to add one series of data with date-formatted `XValues`, and then your code works.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1v0s8ldwHRYUWUtRWpqblgzM3M/edit?usp=sharing

```
Sub AshOriginalWithAddSeries()

Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim dummyDate As Date

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=202, Width:=340, Top:=28, Height:=182).Chart

dummyDate = DateSerial(2013, 2, 1)

' remove extra series
With cht
    Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
        .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop

    'Add at least one series:
     Set srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With srs
        .Name = "Series Title"
        .Values = 0.5 '=Working!$C$3:$C$14" ' or you can pass an array of stored values
        .XValues = Array(dummyDate) '"=Working!$B$3:$B$14" 'or you can pass an array of values, make sure they are valid DATES though
    End With

    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers

    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Performance Trends"
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 12
    .ChartTitle.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .ChartTitle.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"

    With .Axes(xlCategory)
        .CategoryType = xlTimeScale
        '.BaseUnit = xlMonths
        .MajorUnit = 2
        .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mmm yy"
        .TickLabels.Orientation = 45
        '.MajorUnitScale = xlMonths   ' run-time error occurs here
        .MinorUnit = 1
        '.MinorUnitScale = xlMonths


    End With

End With


'Now assign some real values to srs
    With srs
        .Name = "Series Title"
        .Values = "=Working!$C$3:$C$14" ' or you can pass an array of stored values
        .XValues = "=Working!$B$3:$B$14" 'or you can pass an array of values, make sure they are valid DATES though
    End With



End Sub
```

I think your code is failing because there is no series data, and consequently no category values.  It is peculiar because some properties of the axis **can** be set even when the axis doesn't exist. I have noticed similar behavior elsehwere in chart automation -- sometimes it won't let you access the properties unless there is series data.

Comment: thanks again. I made the change you recommended by moving the code which set `.Axes(xlCategory)` properties after adding my data series, but continued to see the same run-time error. So next, I went thru my code again checking for datatype for `.XValues`. It turns out, although my input range was date type format, but just to ensure that x-axis values were in fact date type, I had used the `dateserial` function to assign the input range to an array of double which in turn got assigned to `.XValues`. When I took this code away and instead directly assigned contd...

Comment: contd... the input range to `.Xvalues` the code works just fine. Now that I recall, the date type conversion code came from legacy Excel 2003 sheet. So this error appears related to backward compatibility of `dateserial` function. Anyone care to comment on that? Also, what data type are dates in Excel/vba? Thanks

Comment: Quick update - tried to assign output of `dateserial` function to array of type date. But that results in the (same) run-time error when trying to set `.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnitScale = xlMonths` later in the code.

Comment: not sure about the date conversion issues. my experience working with dates and dateserial conversions has been unpleasant, to say the least. It gets worse when you're working with multiple user locales (e.g., UK date format vs. US date format).

Comment: @ash I updated the code above. I assign some dummy data to the series: a single `Value` and a single `XValue` as array/date as you can see.  I commented out both `MajorUnitScale` and `MinorUnitScale`.  The resulting chart is indistinguishable from the "correct" version -- or at least I can't see a difference.   Then at the end of the code I insert "real" data.  As far as I can tell, the `MajorUnitScale` and `MinorUnitScale` settings aren't necessary; or am I missing something obvious???

Comment: in my case, I'm plotting 24mo. time series data and prefer to set `majorunitscale` to 3mos (excel defaults it to 2mos), since I decided to go with smaller charts so I can fit all information I need on a single page for presentation purposes.In any case, I got the chart I was set out to design. Thx.

Comment: Did you try just setting `MajorUnit = 3` that should do the 3mo interval you want, looks like it works for me.  http://i.imgur.com/tWls3eL.jpg

Comment: as you suggested in the code above, setting `majorunit` without setting `majorunitscale` works. Wonder how excel figures out default settings for `majorunitscale` and appears that its very finicky wrt datatype when trying to override the unitscale setting. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I was able to resolve it by selecting all the cells containing the X axis values, right-clicking to open "Format Cells", and then setting the Number Category (1st tab) to "Date".